# sed not working while extracting lines from a log file?

Tags: bash, shell, date, sed

When I do `echo /$date $hh:$mq[$mr-9]/,/$date 23:59/p`, I get this in return `/2017-12-31 19:1[4-9]/,/2017-12-31 23:59/p` but when I do this `sed -n '/$date $hh:$mq[$mr-9]/,/$date 23:59/p' $error_log_file_name` I get this

> gesed: -e expression #1, char 22: Invalid range end

Any suggestion where I'm going wrong? `$error_log_file_name` is correct.

Comment: Please post sample Input_file and sample expected output in code tags in your post too, so that we could understand your question better.

Comment: @shellter - why what is wrong with my question? why did you felt the need that I should go through those links ?

Answer (score 1):

because without quotes $date variable is expanded,and within single quotes there is no expansion, compare

```
echo /$date $hh:$mq[$mr-9]/,/$date 23:59/p
echo "/$date $hh:$mq[$mr-9]/,/$date 23:59/p"
echo '/$date $hh:$mq[$mr-9]/,/$date 23:59/p'
```

also without quotes, arguments are split on space or tabs and file globbing can occur.